# Array implementation of Stack in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops, data-structures, stack

```
    #include <stdio.h>

#define MAXSIZE 101

int A[MAXSIZE];
int top=-1;
    int data;
void push()
{

    printf("Enter a number\n");
    scanf(" %d",&data);

    if (top==MAXSIZE-1){
        printf("Overflow.Array size limit reached\n");
        return;
    }
    A[++top]=data;
}

void pop()
{
    if(top==-1){
        printf("Empty Stack!\n");
        return;
    }
    top--;
}

int isEmpty()
{
    if(top==-1)
    {
        printf("Empty yes\n");
        return 0;
    }

}

int first()
{
    return A[top];
}

int printStack()
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<=top;i++)
    {
        printf("%d \n",A[i] );
    }
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int choice;
    int flag=1;

    do{
        printf("The options are\n");
        printf("1\t\t Push\n2\t\t Pop\n3\t\t Empty\n4\t\t Top\n5\t\t Print\n\n");

        scanf(" Enter choice %d",&choice);
        switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
            push();
            break;
        case 2:
            pop();
            break;
        case 3:
            isEmpty();
            break;
        case 4:
            first();
            break;
        case 5:
            printStack();
            break;
        default:
            printf("Please enter correct menu choice");

    }

    printf("Wanna repeat again ? Press 1 to repeat 0 to exit\n");
    scanf("%d",&flag);


    }while(flag);

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to create an implementation of Stack using arrays. I am having some problem in the loop. The program runs, it asks for the choice and from switch case driven menu it should go to that function, perform it and come back to main()

But there's some problem and it starts the loop again without performing any function

Comment: Please learn how to debug your program: use a debugger or simply start by putting `printf` here and there to observe the behavior or your program. Read the help text of SO.

Comment: How do you know it isn't performing any function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scanf(" Enter choice %d",&choice);
```

is not a valid way of writing a `scanf()` function. To show a message on the screen we have `puts()` and `printf()` but `scanf()` is used only for getting input. The abnormal behaviour is explained here:

[scanf() reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

To do your task of showing a message to the screen and then taking the input from the user, rewrite the statement as:

```
printf("Enter your choice ");
scanf("%d", &choice);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your scanf statement to :

```
printf("Enter your choice :");
scanf("%d", &choice);
```

Comment: Okay, but perhaps you could explain *why*.

Comment: Because scanf reads from the console , it does not print to the console.

Comment: @Caleb To print to the console we use printf ()

Comment: I understand that. My point was that just giving a couple lines of correct code doesn't make for a good answer, and that you should edit your answer to explain why your code solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to understand stacks as a data structure by implementing it as a structure. By creating a stack structure you can create multiple stacks easily.

```
struct stack {
    int data[MAX];    //define max
    int top;    //top of stack
} s1,s2,s3;     //create multiple stack variables
```